Module 'importlib.resources' has no attribute 'files'
I'm working on some graphs using NetworkX using Spyder and I've encountered this error involving the importlib.resources.
Here's my code.
import networkx as nx
from importlib import files

# Create an empty undirected graph
graph = nx.Graph()

# Add edges to the graph
edges = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1)]
for edge in edges:
    graph.add_edge(*edge)

# Compute graph metrics
diameter, circumference, radius = nx.diameter(graph), nx.average_shortest_path_length(graph), nx.radius(graph)
print("Diameter:", diameter)
print("Circumference:", circumference)
print("Radius:", radius)


The output error is:
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\networkx\generators\atlas.py:54
    ATLAS_FILE = importlib.resources.files("networkx.generators") / "atlas.dat.gz"

AttributeError: module 'importlib.resources' has no attribute 'files'

I am not familiar with the importlib package and I cannot really identify the cause of this problem
